# SortBy with a 2nd argument that specifies not to sort the list?

Tags: functions, sorting

One can specify the second argument of `SortBy` not to sub-sort ties, i.e. cases that have identical values according to the main sorting function. `SortBy[list, {First}]` ensures that sublists are sorted by the first (real) element, and ties are not resolved but left in the order they appear in the original list.

```
list = {{.1, {0, 1, 2}}, {.4, {1}}, {.1, {0, 1}}, {.7, {0}}};

Column /@ {list, SortBy[list, First], SortBy[list, {First}], SortBy[list, {}], SortBy[list, Identity]}
```

[image]

How can I specify a second argument for `SortBy` that leaves `list` as is, without actually sorting it? Clearly, `{}` or `Identity`, `{Identity}`, etc. do not achieve this.

While I strongly believe this cannot be done, as `SortBy` is a function specifically designed to sort, I nevertheless post this as there may be some undocumented way to do it simply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would have expected `SortBy[list,{}]` to also work, but at least the following seems to do the trick:

```
SortBy[list, {0 &}] === list
(* True *)
```

This is effectively using the "stable-sort" property of `SortBy[...,{func}]` with a "useless" sorting function that always returns the same value (0 in this case)

Comment: This is surprising. Where do you learn about the "stable-sort" property? This doesn't seem to be mentioned in document of `SortBy`.

Comment: @xzczd I can't recall how I first learned about it, but it's mentioned a few times on this site, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/3032376) it is explicitly called out. I think I also saw a question about being documented or not, but I can't find it now...

Comment: I also assumed that sorting is stable, and I am surprised that I cannot find this in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
i = 0; SortBy[list, i++&]
```

Or skip `SortBy` with upvalue:

```
SortBy[l_, nosort] ^:= l
SortBy[list, nosort]
```

Comment: These are nice, but in my case I need a solution that **only** involves the 2nd argument of `SortBy`. For context: I define sorting as an option to a higher level function that is internally passed on as the 2nd arg to `SortBy`, without modification. I rather not have users specify contrived sorting functions by meddling with either global variables or upvalues just to pass it on as an option.

Comment: @IstvánZachar How about including the `nosort` as a symbol in the package? (I guess it's a package?)

Comment: That could work, but then again the user has to remember another custom symbol (I already have 300+). For the case at hand, Lukas's answer is exactly what I was looking for.